# Request handler unable to render view with Vision plugin

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, hapijs-vision

I'm working on a HapiJS api and I've defined a plugin that registers the Vision plugin and configures a rendering engine (ejs). But when I try and respond to the request by rendering a view I get the error

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing views manager

If I register the Vision plugin and its config somewhere outside the plugin the tests pass but my expectation is that I should be able to encapsulate this logic in a plugin.

```
// plugin
const ejs = require('ejs');
const Vision = require('vision');

module.exports = {
    name: 'views',
    version: '0.0.1',
    register: async (server, { path }) => {
        await server.register(Vision);
        server.views({
            engines: { ejs },
            path,
        });
    },
};
```

The handler code is

```
// api
server.route({
  path: '/korin/songs',
  method: 'GET',
  handler: async (request, h) => {
    try {
      const acceptType = getMediaType(request.headers.accept);
      const data = await server.methods.getTopTracks({
        getTopTracks,
        lastfmApi,
      });
      if (acceptType === 'text/html') {
        return h.view('index'); // <-- this errors
      }
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
  },
});
```

The error is generated by a failing test which is

```
suite('render content', () => {
    test.only(`given text/html page should respond with header and footer`, async () => {
        const { server } = await setup();
        const { payload } = await server.inject({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/korin/songs',
            headers: {
                accept: 'text/html',
            },
        });

        expect(payload).to.contain(`<header>`);
        expect(payload).to.contain(`<footer>`);
    });
});
```

```
// test setup
const setup = async options => {
    const server = new Hapi.Server();

    // truncated for brevity
    await server.register({
        plugin: require('../../server/api'),
        options: {
            ...defaults,
            ...options,
        },
    });

    await server.register({
        plugin: require('../../server/views'),
        options: { path: path.join(__dirname, '../views/templates') },
    });

    return {
        server
    };
};
```

Is there something I'm missing? I've tried running a console.log and the code seems to be running in the right order but failing anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [old thread on GitHub](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2278) about this. TL;DR: the reference to `server` passed to the plugin when registering is *slightly not the same* as the "root" `server`. Some difference about *realms*, apparently still an issue.

Indeed: in the plugin, `server.getViewsManager()` (decorated by `vision`) after registration of `vision` and `server.views` will show something, whereas the same call in your route (so, after plugin registration) will show `null`. So much for "references".

I just tried a similar structure to you, got the same error, and this thread pointed me to a workaround: when registering your `views` plugin, just pass along a reference to the "real" `server` in the options.

```
// plugin
const ejs = require('ejs');
const Vision = require('vision');

module.exports = {
    name: 'views',
    version: '0.0.1',
    register: async (server, { path, realServer }) => { // <= added option
        await realServer.register(Vision); // <= replaced server w/ realServer
        realServer.views({ // <= replaced server w/ realServer
            engines: { ejs },
            path,
        });
    },
};
```

```
// test setup
// ...
    const server = new Hapi.Server();
    // ...
    await server.register({
        plugin: require('../../server/views'),
        options: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, '../views/templates'),
            realServer: server // <= added option
        }
    });
```

And, obviously, have the same options everywhere you register this plugin.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. I've noticed this doesn't work either `sinon.spy(server, "register")`. when I looked at the source I think I remember seeing the server getting cloned or something.

Comment: in which version did you used this code block? I'm using ```18.1.0``` version and realServer param comes as undefined when I tried to use it @Peter

Comment: sorry - i don't remember now - it was a while ago and i've changed the source significantly @hardc0der :/